# How to Re-register a device in Apple's Provisioning Portal?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-provisioning

I used up all my 100 device registrations and I'm going to be renewing my subscription soon (in about a month.) So I removed unneeded devices so I would have openings available once my renewal kicks in. Unfortunately, I removed one too many and now I want to put it back in.

Is there a way to re-register a device even when the "add" button is no longer in the UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I'm sorry - you must wait until your renewal kicks in. If you reached your 100 device limit you can't remove and then add devices, you just have to wait. If it's really desperate I'd suggest getting in touch with Apple support, although I'm not sure how much good it will do.

Comment: I don't want to add a device exactly. I just want to put a device in that had been there before.

Comment: Unfortunately I guess Apple's systems don't see it that way...best thing to do is email Apple support and hope you make some headway with them.